# How to remove WooCommerce shop images?

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, categories, archive

I'm trying for few hours now to disable the images from my woocommerce shop but couldn't find any solution yet, here's a screenshot of how the shop page (not product page) is looking now and what I want to remove:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVC7E.jpg

I've already tried adding:

// Remove product images from the shop loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

// Remove sale badges from the shop loop
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );

In functions.php, but that image is still there.

Thank you.

Comment: are you not having the product image? if you upload product image than it will automatically go away. this is wordpress default placeholder.

Comment: Thanks Constantin :) … You can add it as an edit at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if it is shop page

```
function before_imageless_product() {
 if( !has_post_thumbnail( get_the_id() ) ){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    echo '<div class="no-image">';
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'before_imageless_product', 9 );

function after_imageless_product() {
 if( !has_post_thumbnail( get_the_id() ) ){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',      'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    echo '</div>';
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'after_imageless_product', 9 );
```

Comment: Didn't worked, I've also tried to set a random image to my product and it didn't disappeared.

Comment: Can you share the code i guess it is product detail page or with shop page you did something wrong

Comment: Post your answer so other can check

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
.products .box-image {display:none;}
.products .product-small .box-text {display:flex!important; } 
.products .product-small .price-wrapper {margin:20px;}
```